# I want to create something that will basically go "IF Q = O THEN DELETE Q"

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't worked with macros in a while so I'm very, very rusty and this may be above the ability I had to begin with.

I only want to delete the contents of the indiviual Q Field, not the row or the column or anything, all the things I've found regarding deleting things in macro's include deleting the row

Replacing Q with NULL would also be a solution, if that's easier to do?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Practice with the autofilter until you get it working the way you want, then use the macro recorder to get a code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you have already *Select*ed the cells you wish to process:

```
Sub ZeroTest()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In Selection
      If r.Value = 0 Then
         r.ClearContents
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

It is a matter of wording.

If you say *Delete a cell*, some would assume you wish to move the undeleted cells up or to the left and some would assume you wish to remove the cell's contents.

If you say *Clear a cell* every one would assume the same thing.

Comment: Right so what I wanted to do was CLEAR a cell, not Delete a cell.

That explains why I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You might also try Find & Replace zero with nothing - making sure you select the option 'Match entire cell contents' !